# How to detect if gtag failed to send an event?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using gtag to send a custom event to Google Analytics 4, the code can be as simple as:

```
gtag('event', 'page_view')
```

There are cases when this request fails, it could be due to adblockers or any other network issues. I would like to be able to catch that and perhaps log to my server.

I tried to use event_callback which is mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference/parameters
It seems like the callback is triggered even when the actual request is blocked.

I could not find any other resources that mention a solution to this.

Comment: Why do you need any other resources? It's not a popular problem because there are better ways to quantify the number of people with ad-blockers and better ways to debug the tracking and ensure data quality. Just use the callback if you tested it and it works when the request is blocked. Although I believe some adblockers would just completely block gtm and gtag.js from loading. But you define gtag(). You can define parallel tracking in it.

Comment: If you believe that adblocker colud be the reason, just remove that code and find the root cause to fix it.

Comment: @BNazaruk I do have code to detect if gtag is completedly blocked. The issue is when it is not completely blocked but somehow the event callback failed.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? It looks like your solution should be changed completely.